# SharePoint field not showing data in Edit Mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, edit

I have an announcement list which stores information. There is a particular field called "Description of Incident" which stores data in Rich Text format. Actually, it stores email as it comes in. It works fine when I am in the View Mode. But when I switch to Edit Mode the data disappears. Can anyone tell me why this happens? And, I did go to the list, clicked on New Edit form, though I haven't added anything new to the list.

In view Mode

[image: In view mode]

In Edit Mode

[image: In Edit mode]

Comment: Have you got 'append content' turned on? So in edit mode it would show nothing?

Comment: It was in 'append content' "Yes". But I changed it to No and still the same problem and the funny thing is when I changed it, the data which was showing up in the view mode became blank as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 'append content' selected for a field, then in edit mode you don't see the full history. You need to view version history to see the content added.

When you changed this setting back to No then you will have been advised the field settings were changed so you have 'blanked' out the history